# Running Xcode 5.0 with 10.7.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, operating-system

I need to run Xcode 5.0 to connect with my devices, which are in iOS 7.0. The problem is my Mac OS is 10.7.5. Xcode 5.0 minimum requirement is 10.8.4. Is there anyway that I can upgrade Mac OS to 10.8 without paying 20$? 
What happen if I install this combo file:
http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1659
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest investing that $20 for upgrade and use the time instead to find coupons for other daily items that you may purchase to make up for that $20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X Mavericks is a free upgrade. You should be able to do an in-place upgrade directly from Lion to Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [**Buy** OS X Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/au/osx/how-to-upgrade/) (or [OS X Mavericks](https://www.apple.com/au/osx/preview/), if it's available to you).

[The OS X Mountain Lion Update v10.8.4 (upgrade)](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1659) to which you linked is a free minor upgrade for existing OS X Mountain Lion users and will not apply to systems running OS X Lion (or earlier).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no legal way to save this 20$, you'r gonna pay them. 
For  http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1659, check the System Requirments and you can see that it requires OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.